# teamcity ci/cd - how to install composer and phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

In TeamCity and CI/CD I want to automate the pipeline of my laravel project.

I'm stuck right now in build steps - since I'm using php I need to install php, composer and phpunit test, but I don't know which commands I should use to install php composer and phpunit. Does anyone know the commands?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @Oussama, please consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), before asking a new question.